# Javascript syntax used in hiding html column

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am looking at code that toggles displaying and hiding a table column.

I am assuming this creates an array:

```
var States = { };
```

Why no need for the [new operator](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_array)?

Does this line set the States col element .isOpen property to  true?

```
States[col] = {isOpen : true};
```

I am figuring out how to modify this function so I can save the state of this column with a cookie. i.e. - when page is rendered, column is set to none by default. However, if the last operation was show column and the page is re-rendered I would like the column to still be open, not go back to default.

The code:

```
/**************************************************************************
 *
 * Function:    toggleVis
 *
 * Description: Following Function hides and expands the main column.
 *              
 *
***************************************************************************/
// Set the default "show" mode to that specified by W3C DOM
// compliant browsers

  var showMode = 'table-cell';


// However, IE5 at least does not render table cells correctly
// using the style 'table-cell', but does when the style 'block'
// is used, so handle this

  if (document.all) showMode='block';

// This is the function that actually does the manipulation

var States = { };

function toggleVis(col){

    if (!States[col] || States[col].IsOpen == null)
    {
        States[col] = {isOpen : true}; // This assumes the cell is already shown
        //States[col] = {isOpen : false}; // This assumes the cell is already hidden
    } 

    //mode =  States[col].IsOpen ? showMode : 'none';
    mode =  States[col].IsOpen ? 'none' : showMode; //starts from closed, next click need open

    cells = document.getElementsByName(col);
    for(j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) cells[j].style.display = mode;

    States[col].IsOpen = !States[col].IsOpen;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var States = {}
```

This creates a new object - arrays and objects are quite similar in javascript, but some subtle differences are there.

```
States[col] = {isOpen : true}
```

creates a new object and puts it into the next index of the States object. You can now access this value using States.col1.isOpen for example.

I notice you have two different ways of typing: IsOpen en isOpen, this is probably causing a problem for you.

Next you have to set the cookie with the information you want - take a peek at this URL:
http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Re: the lower case 'isOpen', this actually works? When I replace it with a capital IsOpen the first click does nothing, or sets it to the default- close. Then the next click after that toggles, etc. I don't get how that has anything to do with this behavior?

Comment: Javascript is case-sensitive, you're probably running into an isOpen/IsOpen clash

Comment: That, or your initial state causes javascript to set the table state to what it already is, after which the isOpen variable and the actual state of the table sync up

Comment: Check out the code in the toggle function. When States[col].isOpen is not set, it is initialized to 'true'. If isOpen is true, mode is set to 'none', thus hiding the previously visible column. The problem is, this also goes for a column without a value which was probably hidden to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,  Maybe this is way off base but I think you are doing this entirely the wrong way.

1. Download jQuery and install it (it's
   about 17kb, a tiny bit of overhead).
2. When you generate your page give each td in a given column a common class such as class='col2'.
3. Use your scripting library to remove hide all the cells.

   $('.col2).hide()

To show the column you use the show function:

```
$('.col2').show()
```

You are done.

Things like this are so much easier with the correct libraries it's painful to see it done other ways.

Comment: yeah, I know it is painful, can't add jQuery however.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax, `var States = { }`, uses [JSON notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) to create a new object.

Similarly, `{isOpen : true}` creates a new object that has an `isOpen` property equal to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You need some basic concepts:

**FIRST**

A cookie is just a specially formatted string, accessible as a property on the document object:

[document.cookie](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#doccookie)

You can simply save the state at the end of the toggleVis function:

```
  ...
  States[col].IsOpen = !States[col].IsOpen;

  // uses the function from quirksmode.org
  createCookie("colState", States[col].IsOpen, 7 /*days until expiration*/);
}
```

and read the cookie on window load (this is just pseudocode):

```
window.onload = function() { 
  // States[col] = readCookie("colState"); 
  // set the style for the columns
};
```

**SECOND**

An object is declared by using curly braces, and variable names ARE case-sensitive.

```
States[col] = { isOpen : true };
```

is NOT THE SAME as

```
States[col] = { IsOpen : true };
```

You seem to have this bug in your code because you try to read IsOpen but set isOpen.